# Problem with dojo nested dialog modality

Tags: dojo

I am facing the problem with nested dialogs.When you try to open a dialog within a dialog it loose modality. I am using dojo 1.5 lib. Can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be happening.

Have a look at http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/tests/test_Dialog.html and click on the button called 'Show 2 Dialogs'.

Can you replicate the loss of modality on that test page? If not, how do you show your two dialogs?

Comment: Yes this is working on the link.but not in my project.As in the library file dialogs are stored into the stack and for modality length of the stack is checked.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you've ascertained that the dialogs you create are being added to the stack, and that the size of the stack is responsible for controlling the modality, then how can you have a problem? Some code snippets for creating and showing/hiding the dialogs might help

Answer (score 0):

In dialog.js file of dojo, it checks whether the stack has single element and then it calls underlay.show(),so when you open second dialog within a dialog ds.length will be 2 and the condition fails and underlay.show will not be called this time.

```
                var ds = dijit._dialogStack,
                    zIndex = 948 + ds.length*2;
                if(ds.length == 1){ // first dialog
                    underlay.show();
                }
                dojo.style(dijit._underlay.domNode, 'zIndex', zIndex);
                dojo.style(this.domNode, 'zIndex', zIndex + 1);
            }),
```